# Speed up audio books

Tags: audio, speed, audiobook

I listen to large numbers of audio books, and I usually speed them up between 2-3 times.  Previously I've done this with Adobe Audition - which does a really crisp job of this.  However purchasing a license of Audition is a bit expensive.  I've tried Audacity, but the quality is nowhere near as good.  VLC does this pretty good but I'm not able to save the output.

Is anyone aware of an inexpensive tool that does a good job of speeding up audio (while preserving the pitch)?  And be able to save to an mp3.

Comment: Have you tried manaualy changing the bitrate?

Comment: You could pirate the software, not that we at SE support such practices but that is an option too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a bit of research I've settled on [GoldWave](http://www.goldwave.com/) as it seems to do a good job of speeding up audio, while preserving pitch and supports batch processing.  Currently I'm playing around with the trial but will probably register it shortly.  Thanks to everyone who offered suggestions.

Comment: There are now many apps that will do this real time, for instance on Android - Smart AudioBook Player

Answer (score 1):

Just change the bitrate using some of the tools listed [here](http://forum.videohelp.com/threads/213818-How-To-Change-Mp3-Bitrate). For convenience, links are:

[CDex](http://www.videohelp.com/tools/CDex)

[besweet](http://www.videohelp.com/tools/BeSweet)

I am sure there are other tools that can do this also.

Comment: Changing bit rate will only effect the quality of the file and make the files smaller (or larger), could you be referring to the sampling rate - altering this will effect the pitch, which I want to avoid.